# How do you implement content switching in a single page in qooxdoo

Tags: qooxdoo

How to implement the content switch in qooxdoo, switch the contents of the container with click event, and load the data and controller in real time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stack container in order to switch between containers.
If you have troubles how to use the stack container see the demo in the demo browser [here](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/demobrowser/#widget~StackContainer.html). So in order to load the data to your controller you should add a listener for the appear event in the appropriate container :)